# spark "java.io.IOException: No space left on device"

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am running a pyspark job on ec2 cluster with 4 workers.
i get this error :

```
2018-07-05 08:20:44 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 1923.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 21385, 10.0.5.97, executor 3): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.finish(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:260)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.close(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:190)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DummySerializerInstance$1.close(DummySerializerInstance.java:65)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndGet(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.writeSortedFile(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:194)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.closeAndGetSpills(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:416)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:230)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:190)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

i looked at https://forums.databricks.com/questions/277/how-do-i-avoid-the-no-space-left-on-device-error.html

tried increasing shuffle partitioned - same issue .
my data looks fairly evenly partitioned across executors .
i want to try the workaround of assigning Null or None to dataframes , the question is if it will indeed remove intermediate shuffle files , and if the linage will not be kept .

for instance if my code looks like this :

```
df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet(...)
df2= df1.filter()
df3 = df2.groupBy(*groupList).agg(....)
```

and i will put

```
df1 = Null
```

after like 1  - will it save shuffle space , isn't it needed and will be re-computed for df2 , df3 ?

second question - 
will checkpointing df1 or df2 help by breaking the linage?

what is a feasible solution when dealing with data larger than my storage (around 400GB of raw data processed)

**UPDATE**
removing cache of a dataframe between 2 phases that needs this dataframe helped and i got no errors .
i wonder how it help with the intermediate shuffle files .

Answer (score 4):

I did face the similar situation. The reason is the that while using `group by` operations and `joins` data will be shuffled. As this `shuffle` data is temporary data while executing in spark applications this will be stored in a directory that `spark.local.dir` in the `spark-defaults.conf` file is pointing to which normally is a `tmp` directory with less space.

In general to avoid this error in the `spark-defaults.conf` file update the `spark.local.dir` to a location which has more memory.